# Ubuntu Router, cant make NAT work LAN/WAN interface

Tags: networking, ubuntu, router, iptables, nat

Im trying to make my own router using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
I have followed this guide: https://kifarunix.com/configure-ubuntu-20-04-as-linux-router/
The only difference between his setup and mine is that i use vlan tags on LAN interface.

I can ping between vlan on the server, and ping from a switch on LAN interface to the router IP.

I can ping from wan interface to 8.8.8.8 but it wont work from vlan.10 ( LAN interface )

Netplan configuration:

```
network:
 ethernets:
enp1s0:
  dhcp4: true
enp2s0:
  dhcp4: true
vlans:
vlan.10:
  id: 10
  link: enp2s0
  addresses:
    - 10.10.10.1/24
```

version: 2

Output from IPtables

iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state 
RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination 




iptables -S 
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp2s0.10 -o enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -o enp2s0.10 -m state --state 
RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

iptables -t nat -L -n -v

```
 Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 1734 packets, 193K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination          

 Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1734 packets, 193K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

 Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 3 packets, 712 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

 Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 3 packets, 712 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      ens1s0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

UPDATE:
Do i need to route traffic on enp2s0.10?

```
ip route
default via 10.110.100.1 dev enp1s0 proto dhcp src 10.110.100.136 
metric 100 
default via 10.10.30.1 dev enp2s0 proto dhcp src 10.10.30.204 
metric 100 
10.10.10.0/24 dev vlan.10 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.10.1 
10.10.20.0/24 dev vlan.20 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.20.1 
10.10.30.0/24 dev enp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.30.204 
10.10.30.1 dev enp2s0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.10.30.204 
metric 100
```

10.110.100.0/24 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.110.100.136
10.110.100.1 dev enp1s0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.110.100.136 metric 100

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Or help me debug this?

Comment: There’s a possible typo in the outgoing interface name in your NAT rule.

Comment: @DanielB You are right. I changed it to enp1s0 but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: @Pim While not addressing your problem, there are dedicated router OSes that are more secure than configuring an OS or server distro as the router OS - some examples of free ones are [Sophos UTM](https://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/unified-threat-management.aspx) _(as a [software appliance](https://www.sophos.com/en-us/support/utm-downloads.aspx), free for home users)_, [pfSense](https://www.pfsense.org/), [OpenWrt](https://openwrt.org/), etc. with Sohpos UTM and pfSense being built upon full distros, whereas OpenWrt runs on both embedded devices and SoCs, as well as custom hardware setups